# Checking for duplicates in database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in which I have user accounts stored that does contain a VATNr.
Now, I need to check if there are duplicates with the following syntax:

I don't control how VATNr are saved in the datbase, meaning that sometimes they could be prefixed with 'BE' and sometimes not.

Now, I need to make sure that there are no duplicates according to the following:

- A plain number
- 'BE' followed by the same plain number.

This means that the 2 VATNr, (BE123456789) and (123456789) would result in a double, but the 2 VATNr (BE123456789) and (987654312) would not result in a double.

How can I do this with a SQL query?

I thought about using a SubQuery like in the below example, but this doesn't work:

```
SELECT User_ID, UserfirstName, UserLastName, Username, VatNr 
  FROM [User] Original
  WHERE VATnr LIKE '%BE' +
    ( SELECT VatNr FROM [User] WHERE VATnr != '' AND IS NOT NULL AND 
         VatNr NOT LIKE '%BE%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%NL%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%FR%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%DK%'
         AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%DE%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%ATU%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%LU%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%CHE%'
         AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%ESE%'  ) + '%'
```

This does give me the following error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: Can you give us sample data that we can simulate on

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I don't understand why the query in your question has these constants in `LIKE`: `NL`, `FR`, `DE`, etc. If these prefixes could be part of your VAT number, please explain in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second condition inside WHERE return duplicate or more value, can you select the query and check the return value ? Or u you put distinct in the condition query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT VatNr FROM [User] WHERE VATnr != '' AND IS NOT NULL AND 
             VatNr NOT LIKE '%BE%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%NL%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%FR%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%DK%'
             AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%DE%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%ATU%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%LU%' AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%CHE%'
             AND VatNr NOT LIKE '%ESE%'
```

Comment: Hello, it's correct that the SubQuery returns more than 1 single result. So, I want to check if there are doubles according to the above description. So let's say that my subquery returns 10 records, then I need to check if the 10 records are doubles (BE prefixed).